# Checking list indexes against other lists and shuffling when they match

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I have multiple lists of items, that I need to shuffle to make sure that:

-An item at a given index in one list, is not in the same place as in another

-The last item of a list is not the same as the first item as the next list

I have written the code below to iterate and do the checks, but it runs forever and then times out. The lists are quite long, so the likelihood of them having matching values is low, I just need to make sure it doesn't happen. I think there must be an error within the loop, I just cannot spot it.

```
shuffled_list = True
while shuffled_list:
    shuffled_list = False
    
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if (
            list1[i] == list2[i] or
            list1[i] == list3[i] or
            list1[i] == list4[i] or
            list2[i] == list3[i] or
            list2[i] == list4[i] or
            list3[i] == list4[i]
        ):
            random.shuffle(list1)
            random.shuffle(list2)
            random.shuffle(list3)
            random.shuffle(list4)
            shuffled_list = True
            break
            
        if  list1[i][-1] == list2[i][0]:
            random.shuffle(list1)
            random.shuffle(list2)
            shuffled_list = True
            break
        
        if  list2[i][-1] == list3[i][0]:
            random.shuffle(list2)
            random.shuffle(list3)
            shuffled_list = True
            break
        if  list3[i][-1] == list4[i][0]:
            random.shuffle(list3)
            random.shuffle(list4)
            shuffled_list = True
            break
            
    if not shuffled_list:
        break
```

Comment: Your checks seem inconsistent.  What do your lists contain?  Do they contain strings?  If so, then `list1[i][-1] == list2[i][0]` is checking the last character of `list1[i]` vs. the first character of `list2[i]`.  If you want to compare list elements, then those checks should be outside of the loop and should not have the `[i]` index.

Comment: In any case, it would help if you provided a complete example.

Comment: The lists contain strings. The issue was with the index, removing the index so it just checks last word against first word has sorted the issue. It was a copy and pasting error which meant I left the [i] in. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that those checks don't belong in the inner loop, since they don't depend on the loop index.  Putting them in the inner loop is a logic error, which results in the same checks being made over and over again for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Reshuffling everything when you encounter a conflict is bound to create more conflicts.  A better strategy would be to progressively shuffle each list ensuring that it doesn't create a conflict with preceding lists.  Cumulatively all lists will meet your criteria.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
list3 = [7,8,9,0,1,2]
list4 = [2,4,6,8,0,3]

lists = [list1,list2,list3,list4]   # list of lists
for i,lst in enumerate(lists):
    while True:                     # shuffle lst until no conflict
        random.shuffle(lst)
        if any(n in col for *col,n in zip(*lists[:i+1])):  
            continue                      # column conflict
        if i and lst[0]==lists[i-1][-1]:                   
            continue                      # last/first conflict
        break                             # no conflict
```

output:

```
print(*lists,sep="\n")

[1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2]
[6, 4, 7, 5, 8, 3]
[9, 1, 0, 7, 2, 8]
[0, 8, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

The condition to check conflicts across columns uses `zip(*lists[:i+1])` to get tuples with the numbers in each column up to the current list.  It separates this into `col` (values of column on previous lists) and `n` value on the current list.  If `n` is present in the same column of previous lists, then there is a conflict and the shuffling loop will continue iterating.

To check the second condition, the first item of the current list (`lst[0]`) is compared to the last item of the previous list (`lists[i-1][-1]`).

*Note that, since you stated that the probability of conflict is low, this approach should not get into dead-end situations where there are no possible shuffling order for a list.  If that possibility exists, you would need some form of backtracking to restart or go back to shuffling a previous list (worst case a dynamic programming solver)*

Here is the same algorithm but with a reset mechanism when shuffling doesn't work after x attempts on the same list (the number of attempts is the length of list but you can chose any number you want):

```
lists = [list1,list2,list3,list4]   # list of lists
i = 0
while i<len(lists):
    lst = lists[i] 
    for _ in lst:              # shuffle lst until no conflict or x times
        random.shuffle(lst)
        if any(n in col for *col,n in zip(*lists[:i+1])):  
            continue           # column conflict
        if i and lst[0]==lists[i-1][-1]:                   
            continue           # last/first conflict
        i += 1
        break                  # no conflict (next list)
    else: i = 0                # still conflicts, restart
```